# prove or disprove convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Im trying to prove or disprove the following , but I am having a hard time.
It seems that the statement is true , but I have no idea how to prove it.

If

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n} a_{n}^2
\end{equation*}

is converging , then

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n} \frac{|a{_n}|}{n}
\end{equation*}

is also converging.
Thanks in adavance!

Comment: Do you mean $\sum a_n^2$ and $\sum \frac{|a_n|}{n}$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please provide some extra context, so people know what type of things you already know that could help you. For example, say where you got this problem, or explain your own thoughts about where to search for a solution.

Comment: yes , that's what i meant , Im new to this math formatting.

Comment: thanks a lot! it helped me

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

> $$\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{\lvert a_n \rvert}{ n } \leq \sqrt{ \sum_{k=n}^\infty a_n^2 }\sqrt{ \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} } < \infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

By the AM-GM inequality, $\displaystyle\frac{|a_n|}{n}\le\frac{1}{2}\big(a_n^2+\frac{1}{n^2}\big)$, so $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|a_n|}{n}$ converges by the Comparison Test.